# ASP.net: TextBox allows out of the range numbers when typed through keyboard in TextMode = "Number"

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms, textbox

I want a TextBox value between 1 and 99 with NumericUpDown in ASP.net webforms. (without using NumericUpdown Extended Ajax Control Toolkit because my client doesn't allow that). So, for that I'm using the following code:

```
<asp:TextBox TextMode="Number" runat="server" min="1" max="99" step="1" ID="tbRooms" />
```

This works fine when I use up and down arrow keys, it ranges only between 1 and 99 as expected. However, when I type the values from the keyboard, it takes any random value, let's say 1000. I tried to put `MaxlLength = "2"` but that didn't work out. So, how can I resolve the issue, so that it doesn't allow any random number even through the keyboard.

Thanks.

Comment: Try [User Input Validation in ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972961.aspx)

Comment: Add a range validator to the textbox.

Comment: you don't want them to be able to type 1000 ?? or you want to tell them to type something between 1 and 99 when thy type 1000 ?

Comment: Should it be asp:TextBox instead of asp:TextMode?

Comment: @abramlimpin is right. :)

Comment: @abramlimpin Yes, right, that was a typo, edited it.

Comment: @Creator I don't want them to be able to type 1000 or any number greater than 99 and less than 1.

Answer (score 5):

Please try this one:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <b>Enter Value</b>
            <asp:textbox runat="server" id="txtRangeValidator">
            </asp:textbox>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <asp:rangevalidator ID="Rangevalidator1" errormessage="Please enter value between 1-99." forecolor="Red" controltovalidate="txtRangeValidator" minimumvalue="1" maximumvalue="99" runat="server" Type="Integer">
            </asp:rangevalidator>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

onKeyPress add this code:

onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==2) return false;"